# Merge tag [symbol] with [symbols]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Currently the description of [symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symbol) is:

> A synonym for [symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symbols).

I suggest they should be merged.

Read: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/symbol/info

Comment: What is the benefit of a merge over a synonym? (that's a genuine question, I'm not dismissing the idea) - oh wait, that's just the description but it's not actually a synonym?

Comment: Merging will make search result more unified.

Comment: While we're at it, should [tag:symbols] be split up, considering the multiple meanings it has?